# how do i get my image to stay at the bottom of the div while it is resizing?

Tags: html, css

I need an image to resize with the browser but I also need it to stay at the bottom of the div it is in. It also needs to be centered in the div.

This is my html:

```
    <div id="logo">
       <img src="/images/logo_2016.jpg"> 
    </div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    max-height: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left 0px;
    background-color:blue;
}

#logo img {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I am using a "position:relative" for the image so it can be centered with "margin:auto". When the browser is resized the image shrinks accordingly but it also stays at the top of the div. I need it to resize and stay at the bottom of the div.

How can I accomplish centering, resizing and staying at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

the container must have position:relative and the child position:absolute - not the other way round:

`<div style="position:relative;height:200px">
<img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="position:absolute;left:50%;bottom:0;margin-left:-22px;"/>
</div>`

the value of margin-left is half of the image width.`

example: https://jsfiddle.net/kbfrufr2/1/

**update:**
if the parent container must have position:absolute you have to introduce a wrapper, which is position:relative:

https://jsfiddle.net/wgLq1yaa/

@cale_b: the mixing of percentage and absolute values is necessary, because 25% would be 25% of container - not of img-tag

Comment: Why not `margin-left: -25%;`?  Mixing percentages and pixels is a recipe for problems....

Comment: If I change the position of the child to absolute, the positioning gets all screwed up. It is no longer centered and it moves up somewhat.

Comment: Basically changing the positioning around solved the problem, so I'll mark this answer correct. However my problem was more complicated than just switching the positions so I'll edit my post to reveal the total answer. Ultimately, I wanted my image to stay at the bottom of a div whose bottom was at 50% of the height of the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding bottom:0; to the #logo img css should keep it positioned at the bottom of its the #logo div